# table reload not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have used navigation controller and 3 screens A,B,C. I have used navigation controller delegate method in A ,where i have reload table data. Now when i m going same in B.But this time Class A delegate and table reload not working,same time Class B delegate and table reload is working. So here how can I reload table in B when that view will appear???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the all the 3 tableview 's delegate & datasource property...

using code :

```
tblView.delegate = self;

tblView.dataSource = self;
```

Then your problem will be solved...

Comment: iam using same table for 3 scenarios and already set the delegate and datasource. Thaank you..!